# Autogenerate a thumb nail image from an .FLV in .net?

Tags: .net, flv

Is there a way to autogenerate a thumb nail image from an .FLV in .net?

Comment: It seemed straightforward enough to me: "How can I take a Flash Movie file (.FLV) and extract an image to serve as a thumbnail for the movie iteself? I want to avoid having to take a screenshot of the playing movie or some other inelegant hack."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it will be two steps which I'm not sure counts as "autogenerated"

1. Framegrab the image with a program such as [Media Handler Pro](http://www.mediasoftpro.com/video-thumbnails.html)
2. Resize the grabbed image to thumbnail size.

FYI: the Media Handler Pro free version supports frame grabs of "320x240 size video or thumbnail will be generated while using any Media Handler Pro function"